# Using Django class based views, how do I create a form where I can add an arbitrary amount of related objects?

Tags: django, django-forms

In my example, let's talk about a database that stores actors and the films they have been in.

I would have a model for actors, and a model for films.

I would like two different forms. The first form would be for creating multiple actors at one time. The second form would be a "detail" create, in where I would only be creating one actor, but on that form I would also be able to enter in an arbitrary amount of films that actor has been in (each film having it's own input field that I would add or remove using javascript).

How do I go about creating these forms and validating them?

Comment: This is called an inline formset. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Answer (score 1):

What you're after here is formsets. The first is a simple ModelFormset, the second is an InlineModelFormset.

Unfortunately, for reasons I've never understood, there is no built-in generic view to handle formsets. The third-party [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) provides them, though.